# java replace German umlauts

Tags: java

I have the following problem. I am trying to replace german umlauts like **ä**, **ö**, **ü** in java. But it simply does not work. Here is my code:

```
private static String[][] UMLAUT_REPLACEMENTS = { { "Ä", "Ae" }, { "Ü", "Ue" }, { "Ö", "Oe" }, { "ä", "ae" }, { "ü", "ue" }, { "ö", "oe" }, { "ß", "ss" } };
public static String replaceUmlaute(String orig) {
    String result = orig;

    for (int i = 0; i < UMLAUT_REPLACEMENTS.length; i++) {
        result = result.replaceAll(UMLAUT_REPLACEMENTS[i][0], UMLAUT_REPLACEMENTS[i][1]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

An **ä** remains an **ä** and so on. I do not know if this issue has something to do with encoding, but the String contains the exact character I am trying to replace.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I just tested and this works as expected, the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Works as expected. You should also consider using `String#replace` instead of `String#replaceAll`, since you're dealing with literals and not regular expressions.

Comment: You may want to check your methods input. How're you entering the data for the method? Hard coded? Via CLI?

Comment: Also consider using chars in one-member char arrays to form the letters to replace, representing the umlaut (diaeresis)-using letters as explicit chars formed by Unicode representations.  Look at the extended ASCII code table found here: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html (look under heading "Latin-1 Supplement").  You'd represent Ä, for example, as '\u0x00C4'.  So your first line would look like:               ...UMLAUT_REPLACEMENTS = { { new String({'\u0x00C4'}), "Ae" }, ...

Comment: The data input is a concatenated string from timestamp and user input

Comment: @user2841991 had some problem like this befoe, just try to turn input string to byte code and compare that with "Ä".getBytes(). you should make sure bytes are the same.

Comment: I once had a similar issue, I fixed it by just using a `replace` inside a loop instead of `replaceAll`. But don't ask why one method did work and the other didn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This finally worked for me:

```
private static String[][] UMLAUT_REPLACEMENTS = { { new String("Ä"), "Ae" }, { new String("Ü"), "Ue" }, { new String("Ö"), "Oe" }, { new String("ä"), "ae" }, { new String("ü"), "ue" }, { new String("ö"), "oe" }, { new String("ß"), "ss" } };
public static String replaceUmlaute(String orig) {
    String result = orig;

    for (int i = 0; i < UMLAUT_REPLACEMENTS.length; i++) {
        result = result.replace(UMLAUT_REPLACEMENTS[i][0], UMLAUT_REPLACEMENTS[i][1]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

So thanks to all your answers and help. It finally was a mixture of nafas(with the new String) and Joop Eggen(the correct replace-Statement).
You got my upvote thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

Your code looks fine, `replaceAll()` should work as expected.

Try this, if you also want to preserve capitalization (e.g. `ÜBUNG` will become `UEBUNG`, not `UeBUNG`):

```
private static String replaceUmlaut(String input) {
 
     // replace all lower Umlauts
     String output = input.replace("ü", "ue")
                          .replace("ö", "oe")
                          .replace("ä", "ae")
                          .replace("ß", "ss");
 
     // first replace all capital Umlauts in a non-capitalized context (e.g. Übung)
     output = output.replaceAll("Ü(?=[a-zäöüß ])", "Ue")
                    .replaceAll("Ö(?=[a-zäöüß ])", "Oe")
                    .replaceAll("Ä(?=[a-zäöüß ])", "Ae");
 
     // now replace all the other capital Umlauts
     output = output.replace("Ü", "UE")
                    .replace("Ö", "OE")
                    .replace("Ä", "AE");
 
     return output;
 }
```

[Source](http://gordon.koefner.at/blog/coding/replacing-german-umlauts/)

Comment: Nice, smart dealing with Ue/UE. (`o_str...` however itches). You might want to use replace i.o. replaceAll.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Incorporated your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: This does not work for me. After using this method, my string has not changed at all. The ä is still there.

Comment: This code is working. Update your question and show us how you call your method (or mine). Your input seems problematic.

Comment: I can confirm that this works with `replaceAll()` but not with `replace()` in a current Java version. A possible cause may be the additional flag for regex pattern compilation used by `replace()`.

Comment: @JensPiegsa You don't have to look at `Pattern.LITERAL` in the implementation of `replace`; the javadoc says "literal", too.

Comment: For me this wasn't working (on target platfrom). I had to replace all umlauts by unicode.

Comment: @dermoritz You probably had java file encoding issues. You need to make sure, that you use the same encoding for STORING your java file as for COMPILING it. See command line options on `javac` or similar settings in the IDE or build-chain  you use.

Answer (score 9):

i had to modify the answer of user1438038:

```
private static String replaceUmlaute(String output) {
    String newString = output.replace("\u00fc", "ue")
            .replace("\u00f6", "oe")
            .replace("\u00e4", "ae")
            .replace("\u00df", "ss")
            .replaceAll("\u00dc(?=[a-z\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df ])", "Ue")
            .replaceAll("\u00d6(?=[a-z\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df ])", "Oe")
            .replaceAll("\u00c4(?=[a-z\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df ])", "Ae")
            .replace("\u00dc", "UE")
            .replace("\u00d6", "OE")
            .replace("\u00c4", "AE");
    return newString;
}
```

This should work on any target platform (i had problems on a tomcat on windows).

Comment: This is the only working solution for me. Thanks a lot! Kudos!

Answer (score 4):

**ENCODING ENCODING ENCODING....**

Different source of input may result in complications in the String encoding. for example one may have `UTF-8` encoding while the other one is `ISO`

some people suggested that the code works for them, therefore, its most likely that your Strings have different encoding while processed. (different encoding results in different byte array thus no replacing...)

to solve your problem from its root,you must make sure, each of your sources uses exactly same encoding.

try this exercise  and it hopefully helps you to  solve your problem:

1-try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("Ä".getBytes());  //1 and 2 should have same results
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new String("Ä","UTF-8").getBytes()); //1 and 2 should have same results
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new String("Ä","UTF-32").getBytes()); //should have a different results from one and two
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(orig.getBytes()); //look for representation and search for pattenr of numbers (this bit is the hard bit I guess).
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new String(orig,"UTF-32").getBytes()); //look for representation and search for pattenr of numbers (this bit is the hard bit I guess).
```

the next step is to see how the `orgi` string is formed. for example if you have received from web, make sure your POST and GET method are using your preferred encoding

EDIT 1:

try this:

```
{ { new String("Ä".getBytes(),"UTF-8"), "Ae" }, ... };
```

if this one didn't work try this:

```
    byte[] bytes = {-61,-124}; //byte representation of Ä in utf-8
    String Ae = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");
    { { Ae, "Ae" }, ... }; //and do for the rest
```

Comment: The first two lines do not have the same result for me.

Comment: @user2841991 then check the edit mate, it most likely going to fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to run it and it runs fine.

If you're not using regular expressions then i'd use `string.replace` rather than `string.replaceAll` as it's slightly quicker than the latter. The difference between them mainly being that replaceAll can handle regex's.

EDIT: Just noticed people in the comments have the said the same before me so if you've read theres you can pretty much ignore what I said, as stated the problem exists elsewhere in your code as that snippet works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine when I try it, so it must be an encoding issue.

Check your system encoding. You may want to add `-encoding UTF-8` to your `javac` compiler command line.

```
      -encoding encoding
         Set the source file encoding name, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8. If -encoding is not specified, the platform default converter is used.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache Commons or Commons3 in your project, it would be most efficient to use a class like

```
public class UmlautCleaner {

    private static final String[] UMLAUTE = new String[] {"Ä", "Ö", "Ü", "ä", "ö", "ü", "ß"};
    private static final String[] UMLAUTE_REPLACEMENT = new String[] {"AE", "OE", "UE", "ae", "oe", "ue", "ss"};

    private UmlautCleaner() {
    }

    public static String cleanSonderzeichen(final String s) {
        return StringUtils.stripAccents(StringUtils.replaceEach(s, UMLAUTE, UMLAUTE_REPLACEMENT));
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and plain. That's how I wanted it.

Comment: I also had to deal with special characters and umlauts and so on. After a while, I discovered that stripAccents doesn't deal well with caracters such as a turkish ı or a danish ø. Eventhough I didn't want to pull another dependency, I ended up using Junidecode, that does very well on those characters too.

Answer (score -1):

A short solution is using a transliterator:

```
Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("de-ASCII");
String umlautReplaced = transliterator.transliterate(text);
```

Comment: Transliterator is no standard package, you should at least define where it comes from.