# Data type blob mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, blob

My colleague setup a MySql database. For two fields where one can enter longer text he used database type BLOB. The problem now is when someone is entering German "Umlaute(ä,ö,ü)". These are not shown properly when I retrieve it later from the database to show it to the user. Instead they are shown as weird signs. I mean, in my java code these Blob objects are simple Strings. What can I do to show these special character (Umlaute) properly again?

Comment: This issue has been discuessed on Stack Overflow before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696273/java-replace-german-umlauts

Comment: Set type as longtext

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to change the column type to `TEXT`.

The first B in `BLOB` stands for **binary**. With such column type you're telling MySQL explicitly that you don't want its contents to be handled as text. For that reason, you'd need to ask everyone who enters data what encoding they are using and then make a conversion from that encoding to your application's encoding. Of course, you also don't have any way to control how others are writing and reading data so you could eventually find different encodings in different rows.

BTW, both [BLOB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html#idm140275526727792) and [TEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html#idm140275526714896) have a maximum length of 65,535 (216 − 1) (bytes in the case of BLOB, characters in the case of TEXT), the same as [VARCHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html#idm140275526812544). If you really want large text that don't fit in VARCHAR you may want to consider larger types like [MEDIUMTEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html#idm140275526690896) or [LONGTEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html#idm140275526667840).

Comment: I do not know why my collegue chose BLOB. It works fine except for these special characters like "German Umlaute" . Instead of 1 Umlaut , I see 2 weird characters

Comment: That's because most text encodings in the last 50 years are compatible with US-ASCII. It breaks when you find a character that cannot be encoded in ASCII (or you use a non-ASCII-compatible encoding such as UTF-16).

Comment: so a String in java seems to be not US-ASCII because it can also store special characters like "German Umlaute"

Comment: Java is a language from the mid 1990s, not the 1950s ;-) But the internal encoding is irrelevant: any decent database toolchain converts between encoding transparently and that's exactly what setting the column as binary prevents.